# Parse IP address from a GPRS module reply

Tags: c, parsing, ip-address, c99

I'm writing a parser to get the IP address from a string I get from a GPRS module. Examples of the string I get from the GPRS module:

> +QIACT: 1,1,1,\"10.162.143.228\"\r\n\r\nOK\r\n
>
> +QIACT: 1,1,1,\"10.184.110.91\"\r\r\n+QIACT: 2,1,1,\"10.184.110.91\"\r\n\r\nOK\r\n

The string have the following format:

```
+QIACT: [ctx_id],[ctx_state],1,"[ip_address]"
```

- `ctx_id` is an integer that can go from 1 to 16.
- `ctx_state` is an integer that can be 0 (context deactivated) or 1 (context activated).
- `ip_address` which is the local ip address of the GPRS module.

I made some naive tests and the function is returning what's expected. I'm looking for some feedback/improvements I can do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define CTX_ID_MIN              1
#define CTX_ID_MAX              16
#define CTX_MAX_CNT             CTX_ID_MAX + 1

#define CTX_ACTIVE              '1'

#define INT_TO_ASCII(x)         (x + '0')
#define IS_INVALID_CTX_ID(x)    (CTX_ID_MAX < x || 0 == x)
#define GET_CTX_ID(x)           (*(x + 1))
#define GET_CTX_STATE(x)        (*(x + 1))

struct ctx {
    uint8_t ip[4];
    uint8_t id;
    bool    is_active;
};

/**
 * The AT+QIACT? command will reply the list of the current activated context
 * and its IP address.
 *
 * Reply format: +QIACT: <ctx_id>,<ctx_state>,1,<ip_address>
 *
 * This function parses that reply (qiact_reply), look for the specified ctx_id
 * and verify if it's active, if so it will get the ip address and return true,
 * or return false otherwise.
 *
 * Examples qiact_reply data:
 * +QIACT: 1,1,1,\"10.162.143.228\"\r\n\r\nOK\r\n
 * +QIACT: 1,1,1,\"10.184.110.91\"\r\r\n+QIACT: 2,1,1,\"10.184.110.91\"\r\n\r\nOK\r\n
 */
static bool ctx_get_ip(char *qiact_reply, struct ctx *ctx)
{
    char *cursor = NULL;

    if (IS_INVALID_CTX_ID(ctx->id) || (NULL == qiact_reply)) {
        return false;
    }

    cursor = qiact_reply;

    // valid ctx_id's start at 1
    for (size_t i = 1; i < CTX_MAX_CNT; i++) {

        // Are we pointing to the ctx_id that we are looking for?
        char *_ctx_id = strchr(cursor, ' ');
        if (GET_CTX_ID(_ctx_id) == INT_TO_ASCII(ctx->id)) {
            char *ctx_state = NULL;
            ctx_state = strchr(qiact_reply, ',');
            // Point to the ctx_state field
            if (GET_CTX_STATE(ctx_state) != CTX_ACTIVE) {
                ctx->is_active = false;
                break;
            } else {
                ctx->is_active = true;

                // get the ctx ip
                char *ip_start = NULL;
                char *ip_end = NULL;

                ip_start = strchr(cursor, '"');
                ip_end = strchr(ip_start + 1, '.');

                // ip_start points to the first '"', we have to increment it by
                // 1 so it points to the beginning of the number, ip_end points
                // to the '.'.
                ctx->ip[0] = (uint8_t) strtoul(ip_start + 1, &ip_end, 10);
                // increment ip_start and ip_end
                ip_start = ip_end + 1;
                ip_end = strchr(ip_start, '.');
                ctx->ip[1] = (uint8_t) strtoul(ip_start, &ip_end, 10);
                // increment ip_start and ip_end again
                ip_start = ip_end + 1;
                ip_end = strchr(ip_start, '.');
                ctx->ip[2] = (uint8_t) strtoul(ip_start, &ip_end, 10);
                // increment ip_start and ip_end for the last time
                ip_start = ip_end + 1;
                ip_end = strchr(ip_start, '.');
                ctx->ip[3] = (uint8_t) strtoul(ip_start, &ip_end, 10);

                break;
            }
        } else {
            // Point to the next '+' symbol until we reach the last one
            cursor = strchr(cursor + 1, '+');
            if (NULL == cursor) {
                ctx->is_active = false;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    return ctx->is_active;
}

int main(void) {

    struct ctx my_ctx = {
        .id = 1
    };

    ctx_get_ip("+QIACT: 1,1,1,\"10.184.110.91\"\r\r\n+QIACT: 3,1,1,\"10.185.110.91\"\r\n\r\nOK\r\n", &my_ctx);

    if (my_ctx.is_active) {
        printf("ctx %d is active: %s, ip: %d.%d.%d.%d\r\n", my_ctx.id,
               my_ctx.is_active ? "true" : "false",
               my_ctx.ip[0], my_ctx.ip[1], my_ctx.ip[2], my_ctx.ip[3]);
    } else {
        printf("ctx %d is active: %s\r\n", my_ctx.id,
               my_ctx.is_active ? "true" : "false");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ctx 1 is active: true, ip: 10.184.110.91

Comment: In order to be truly review ready, in my opinion you should implement the improvements you see before asking for review. I don't think that makes your question off-topic, but making the code as good as *you* can make the question *better*

Comment: `static bool ctx_get_ip()` returns `bool` not "Return the list of the current activated context and its IP address.".  What does the return value of `ctx_get_ip()` imply?  Looks more like success/failure.

Comment: @bruglesco I updated the question.

Comment: @chux "The Return the list of the current ..." text was some help from the GPRS module documentation, i updated the code so it doesn't get confused with the actual function behavior.

Answer (score 3):

**Use `const`**

As code does not modify the string at `qiact_reply`, uses `const` for greater functionality (function can then accept `const char *`) and open to more optimizations.  It also conveys to the caller that `qiact_repl` data is not changed.

**Use integer**

I'd expect `CTX_ACTIVE` to be `1` and not `'1'` and scan accordingly.  As defined, it works in OP's code, but is unusual.

**`size_t`**

Good use of `size_t` for array indexing.

**Why `CTX_MAX_CNT`?**

`CTX_MAX_CNT` appears secondary.  I'd limit parsing to the length of the string `qiact_reply`.

**IP: No range protection**<sup>1</sup>

Pedantic code would insure range is [0...255].  That is easier to do with `strtol()` than `strtoul()`.  Not  a big issue though.

**Parsing unclear**

Subjective: I found the code difficult to assess how well it catches all corner cases of invalid input detection.  To that end, I offer an alternative below.  It has weakness<sup>1</sup> too, but I can see them easier.

I've allowed for liberal acceptance of white-space.

I also like the clear idea that `*ctx_ip` is only changed when the function returns `true`.  Alternative code may want to clear `*ctx_ip` on `false`.

```
#define IP_FMT " \"%3" SCNu8 " .%3" SCNu8 " .%3" SCNu8 " .%3" SCNu8 " \""

static bool ctx_get_ip2(const char *qiact_reply, uint8_t ctx_id, struct ip_addr *ctx_ip) {

  if (IS_INVALID_CTX_ID(ctx_id) || (NULL == qiact_reply)) {
      return false; // bad ID or pointer
  }

  const char *s = qiact_reply;
  while (*s) {
    struct ip_addr my_ctx_ip;
    int my_ctx_id;
    char my_ctx_state;
    // Use %n to record scanning offset
    int n = 0;
    sscanf(s, " +QIACT: %2d , %c , 1 ," IP_FMT " %n",  &my_ctx_id, &my_ctx_state, //
        &my_ctx_ip.ip[0], &my_ctx_ip.ip[1], &my_ctx_ip.ip[2], &my_ctx_ip.ip[3],   //
        &n);
    if (n == 0) {
      return false;  // Parsing incomplete, Invalid syntax
    }
    if (my_ctx_id == ctx_id) {
      if (my_ctx_state != CTX_ACTIVE) {
        return false;  // Not active
      }
      *ctx_ip = my_ctx_ip;
      return true;  // Success!
    }
    s += n;  // advance to next
  }
  return false;  // record not found
}
```

Comment: I think and correct me if i'm wrong, casting the found ip octect to uint8_t will make sure it's not bigger than 255. I tried to take into account all other suggestions, check the updated question for the new function. i will study your approach and see which one is "faster" and "smaller".

Comment: @Carlos_47 "casting the found ip octect to uint8_t will make sure it's not bigger than 255" is true for the `ctx->ip[ip_octect]`, but is not true for `ip_start`.  If `ip_start` was `"256"`, that out-of-range text would not be saved correctly nor detected as an error.  It comes down to how robust you want your parser and to avoid being a hacker victim.

Comment: @Carlos_47 Concerning the "updated question.  See [is it okay to edit my own question to include revised code?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c) and its "should not append your revised code to the question.".  Suggest rolling back your edit and post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments i updated the function, i feel more comfortable with it, changes:

- Removed unused macros.
- Macro to init the ctx struct (INIT_CTX).
- ctx_get_ip returns false on invalid data input, true otherwise.
- Replaced the for loop that iterated all the possible ctx id with a while loop that iterate the qiact_reply input until is invalid.
- Validation of the ctx_id found on the qiact_reply input.

What do you think?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define IS_CTX_ACTIVE(x)        ((*(x + 1)) == '1')
#define IS_VALID_CTX_ID(x)      ((CTX_ID_RANGE_MIN <= x) && (CTX_ID_RANGE_MAX >= x))
#define INT_TO_ASCII(x)         (x + '0')
#define GET_CTX_STATE(x)        (*(x + 1))

struct ctx {
    uint8_t ip[4];
    uint8_t id;
    bool    is_active;
};

/**
 * The AT+QIACT? command will reply the list of the current activated context
 * and its IP address.
 *
 * Reply format: +QIACT: <ctx_id>,<ctx_state>,1,<ip_address>
 *
 * This function parses that reply (qiact_reply), look for the specified ctx_id
 * and verify if it's active, if so it will get the ip address and set the
 * is_active member to true.
 *
 * @return false is case of any invalid data, true otherwise.
 *
 * Examples qiact_reply data:
 * +QIACT: 1,1,1,\"10.162.143.228\"\r\n\r\nOK\r\n
 * +QIACT: 1,1,1,\"10.184.110.91\"\r\r\n+QIACT: 2,1,1,\"10.184.110.91\"\r\n\r\nOK\r\n
 */
static bool ctx_get_ip(const char *qiact_reply, struct ctx *ctx)
{
    bool result = false;

    if (!IS_VALID_CTX_ID(ctx->id) || (NULL == qiact_reply)) {
        return result;
    }

    const char *cursor = strchr(qiact_reply, '+');

    // iterate @c qiact_reply while @c cursor points to a '+' sign (it's not NULL)
    while (NULL != cursor) {

        // Find the current <ctx_id> field
        char *ctx_id_s = strchr(cursor, ' ');
        char *ctx_id_e = strchr(ctx_id_s, ',');
        ctx_id_s++;

        uint8_t ctx_id = (uint8_t) strtoul(ctx_id_s, &ctx_id_e, 10);

        // Did we found the ctx id we are looking for?
        if ((ctx_id == ctx->id) && IS_VALID_CTX_ID(ctx_id)) {
            result = true;
            ctx->is_active = false;

            // If so, get the <ctx_state>
            char *ctx_state = strchr(cursor, ',');
            if (IS_CTX_ACTIVE(ctx_state)) {
                ctx->is_active = true;

                // The ctx state is active, let's get the <ip_address>
                char *ip_start = strchr(cursor, '"');
                char *ip_end = strchr(ip_start, '.');
                ip_start++; // point to the digit after '"'

                for (size_t ip_octect = 0; ip_octect < 4; ip_octect++) {
                    ctx->ip[ip_octect] = (uint8_t) strtoul(ip_start, &ip_end, 10);
                    // Move to the next octect, we are here on the second octect
                    ip_start = ip_end + 1;
                    ip_end = strchr(ip_start, '.');
                }
            }

            break;
        } else {
            // Move to the next '+' symbol
            cursor = strchr(cursor + 1, '+');
            if (NULL == cursor) {
                // We reached the end of @c qiact_reply without finding the
                // ctx id we were looking for, let's exit
                ctx->is_active = false;
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

#define INIT_CTX(ctx_id)    \
{                           \
    .id = ctx_id,           \
    .ip[0] = 0,             \
    .ip[1] = 0,             \
    .ip[2] = 0,             \
    .ip[3] = 0,             \
    .is_active = false,     \
}

int main(void) {

    struct ctx my_ctx = INIT_CTX(1);

    bool result = ctx_get_ip("+QIACT: 1,1,1,\"10.184.110.91\"\r\r\n"
                             "+QIACT: 16,1,1,\"10.185.110.91\"\r\n\r\nOK\r\n",
                             &my_ctx);

    if (result) {
        if (my_ctx.is_active) {
            printf("ctx %d is activated, ip: %d.%d.%d.%d\r\n", my_ctx.id,
                   my_ctx.ip[0], my_ctx.ip[1], my_ctx.ip[2], my_ctx.ip[3]);
        } else {
            printf("ctx %d is deactivated\r\n", my_ctx.id);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Invalid input\r\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```